# Extract data with regex from html

Tags: java, html, regex

I would like to extract items from this sample html, more specificly, i would like to isolate the following ones: 
algp1, 
PRODUCTION
50733
GEN_APPL
KANTOOR

```
<table width="95%" border="1">
<tr><td colspan=3><a name="algp1"></a><img src="menu/db2inst.jpg">  <font color="#FF0000" size="+1">algp1</font> (PRODUCTION, 50733)</td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%" valign=top><a name="GENAPPLP"></a><img src="menu/db2db.jpg"><font color="#00CC00"><b> GEN_APPL</font></b><br>(GENAPPLP)</td><td width="15%" valign=top>PARK</td><td width="70%" valign=top><font size="2">BOOKINGCARPARKING&sbquo; CUSTOMERS&sbquo; </font></td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%" valign=top></td><td width="15%" valign=top>RDC</td><td width="70%" valign=top><font size="2">DBREL_SCHEMA_RDCPROJECT&sbquo; DBVERSION&sbquo; </font></td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%" valign=top><a name="KANTOORP"></a><img src="menu/db2db.jpg"><font color="#00CC00"><b> KANTOOR</font></b><br>(KANTOORP)</td><td width="15%" valign=top>CDDB</td><td width="70%" valign=top><font size="2">BATIMENTS&sbquo; BATIMENTS_EXC&sbquo; OFFICES&sbquo; OFFICES_EXC&sbquo; RECETTES&sbquo; RECETTES_EXC&sbquo; </font></td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%" valign=top></td><td width="15%" valign=top>IDR</td><td width="70%" valign=top><font size="2">ADMINISTRATION&sbquo; ADMINISTRATION_EXC&sbquo; ARROND&sbquo; ARROND_EXC&sbquo; BUREAU&sbquo; BUREAU_EXC&sbquo; CODEX&sbquo; CODEX_EXC&sbquo; COMMUNE&sbquo; COMMUNE_EXC&sbquo; COMPETENCE&sbquo; COMPETENCE_EXC&sbquo; COMPTE&sbquo; COMPTE_EXC&sbquo; LNKBCC&sbquo; LNKBCC_EXC&sbquo; LNKBCI&sbquo; LNKBCI_EXC&sbquo; LNKBPC&sbquo; LNKBPC_EXC&sbquo; LNKBS&sbquo; LNKBS_EXC&sbquo; LNKCBRR&sbquo; LNKCBRR_EXC&sbquo; LNKCS&sbquo; LNKCS_EXC&sbquo; MAP_CP_BUREAU&sbquo; PAYS&sbquo; PAYS_EXC&sbquo; PROVINCE&sbquo; PROVINCE_EXC&sbquo; RANGE_RUE&sbquo; RANGE_RUE_EXC&sbquo; REGION&sbquo; REGION_EXC&sbquo; RUE&sbquo; RUE_EXC&sbquo; SERVICE&sbquo; SERVICE_EXC&sbquo; TPCODEX&sbquo; TPCODEX_EXC&sbquo; TPCOMPTE&sbquo; TPCOMPTE_EXC&sbquo; </font></td></tr>
<tr><td width="20%" valign=top></td><td width="15%" valign=top>RDC</td><td width="70%" valign=top><font size="2">DBREL_SCHEMA_RDCPROJECT&sbquo; DBVERSION&sbquo; </font></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Better use a real parser if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). It will parse the HTML and give you a DOM interface to iterate over.

I would strongly recommend not using a regexp for all but the simplest cases. HTML isn't regular and has no end of edge cases to trip you up.

Comment: +1, avoid RegEx the most, because using it you'll have 2 problems.
And please, do a little search before posting, there is a billion times this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299942/regex-matching-html-tags-and-extracting-text and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181095/regular-expression-to-extract-text-from-html and so on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638/what-html-parsing-libraries-do-you-recommend-in-java offers some libraries that do the tidying and parsing. But your answer put me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at regulazy...

It will allow you to create a regexp from an input string with a simple point and click interface.

http://osherove.com/tools/