# Strip ALL HTML from a String?

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen regex that can remove tags, which is great, but I also have stuff like

```
&nbsp;
```

etc.

This isn't actually from a HTML file. It's actually from a string. I'm pulling down data from SharePoint web services, which gives me the HTML users might use/get generated like

```
<div>Hello! Please remember to clean the break room!!! &quot;bob&quote; <BR> </div>
```

So, I'm parsing through 100-900 rows with 8-20 columns each.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), it's an HTML parser that you can use to extract the `InnerText` from HTML nodes in a document.

As has been [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181095/regular-expression-to-extract-text-from-html) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409976/extract-data-with-regex-from-html) [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113651/how-to-extract-text-from-resonably-sane-html) here on SO, you can't trust HTML parsing to a regular expression. There are times when it might be considered appropriate (for extremely limited tasks); but in general, HTML is too complex and too prone to irregularity. [Bad things can happen when you try to parse HTML with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Using a parser such as HAP gives you much more flexibility. A (rough) example of what it might look like to use it for this task:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("path to your HTML document");

StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
{
    if (!node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

You can also perform [XPATH](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php) queries on your document, in case you're only interested in a specific node or set of nodes:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("your XPATH query here");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide actual code that demonstrates how to use HAP to perform the task?