# get text between html tags

Tags: java, regex

> Possible duplicate: [RegEx matching HTML tags and extracting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299942/regex-matching-html-tags-and-extracting-text)

I need to get the text between the html tag like `<p></p>` or whatever. My pattern is this

```
Pattern pText = Pattern.compile(">([^>|^<]*?)<");
```

Anyone knows some better pattern, because this one its not very usefull. I need it to get for  index the content from web page.

Thanks

Comment: In your situation a regex may be ok, but have you read this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: There should be an option *Vote to close: User is parsing HTML with regex*

Answer (score 5):

SO is about to descend on you.  But let me be the first to say, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  [Here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) is a list of Java HTML Parsers.  Look around until you see an API that suits your fancy and use that instead.

Comment: TagSoup is particularly flavorful if you have sloppy HTML to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to use the `|` operator inside a negative set, which is neither working nor needed. Just specify the characters that you don't want to match:

```
Pattern pText = Pattern.compile(">([^<>]*?)<");
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions when parsing HTML.

Use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) instead (if your HTML is well formed). You can reference text nodes using the `text()` function very easily.