# Get a part of data got using HTTPClient

Tags: java, html, http, httpclient

I am using `HTTPClient` to connect to website.

```
byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
```

I now wish to retrieve only a part of the html. i.e. I want text which is displayed after the tags `<td><font size=\"2\">`  and before `</font>`

How should I use split function for the above problem?

I used

```
String[] substr = new String(responseBody).split("<td><font size=\"2\">");
```

but it gives address.

I want the text to be displayed.

How should I go about this issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific what do you mean by text to be displayed. What text you want to retrieve from that.

Comment: @Mutant:
I use the following code to retrieve html code of website
byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

There are six tags 
<td><font size=\"2\">  </font> in the code with data in between them. I want to get that data. How to retrieve it?

Comment: You should use HTML parser like JSOUP. http://jsoup.org/

Comment: @user2822187 - you will need to use pattern as shown in various examples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088412/get-text-between-html-tags

Comment: @Georgy Gobozov:
How do I use byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody(); in
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); I it is giving typecasting error when i use
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new String(responseBody));

Answer (score 0):

For a simple case you could use regex to match and remove all the tags which will leave you with the data.

```
\<[^\>]*\>
```